# How can run 10 minute minus the current time on python?

Tags: python

How can run 10 minute minus the current time on python?

I want continuously subtract 10 minutes from the current time.

But it doesn't work.

What should I do?

### Referenced sites

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

---

### Code attempted

```
import datetime

def before_10minute_time(time):
    
    flag = 0
    
    
    
    if flag == 0:
        current_time = datetime.datetime.today()
        current_time_minute10 = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10) 

        print("현재시간에서 -10분 : ",current_time_minute10.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')) # current_time_minute10_2 = 20210813164951
        flag = 1
        
        
        
    elif flag == 1:
        current_time_minute10_2 = current_time_minute10 - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10) 
        print("현재시간에서 -10분 : ",current_time_minute10_2.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')) # current_time_minute10_2 = 20210813164951
        
        before_10minute_time(current_time_minute10_2)
    
    
    
# ------------------------------- main -------------------------------
current_time = datetime.datetime.today()    
print("현재시간 : ",current_time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')) # current_time = 20210813170951


while True:
    before_10minute_time(current_time)
```

---

### my goals(target)

```
e.g : current_time = 20210813183000 
current_time -10 :  20210813182000 
current_time -10 :  20210813181000 
current_time -10 :  20210813180000 
current_time -10 :  20210813175000 
current_time -10 :  20210813174000
current_time -10 :  20210813173000
current_time -10 :  20210813172000
current_time -10 :  20210813171000
```

> How can run 10 minute minus the current time on python?

Comment: It looks like it works to me. You have a infinite loop and you are printing stuff out. However, `But it doesn't work` is not a description of the symptoms. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "like a target"? Also, note that recursion, which is limited. is not the right tool for an infinite repetition.

Comment: i update title and content of the post.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68770570/how-can-get-an-infinite-loop-to-output-by-july-1-2021/68770761?noredirect=1#comment121537005_68770761) will help you

Answer (score 1):

Isnt this enough?

```
def before_10minute_time(current_time):
    current_time_minute10 = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10)
    print("current_time -10 : " + str(current_time_minute10.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')))
    return current_time_minute10

if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_time = datetime.datetime.today()

    while True:
        current_time = before_10minute_time(current_time)
```

after your comments:

```
def before_10minute_time(current_time):
    current_time_minute10 = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10)
    print(current_time_minute10.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
    return current_time_minute10

if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_time = datetime.datetime(2021,7,1,23,59)

    while current_time > datetime.datetime(2021,7,1,00,00) :
        current_time = before_10minute_time(current_time)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want.
But I have a question.

`Q1. How do I store the resulting value minus 10 minutes in a variable?`

`Q2. Also, is it possible to limit the output to July 1, 21?`

Comment: The resulting value is stored in a variable, current_time. Use datetime.date(2021, 7, 1) to get that date but I dont know how to limit it in this infinite loop. Why has the loop to be infinite anyway?