# How can get an infinite loop to output by July 1, 2021?

Tags: python

How can get an infinite loop to output by July 1, 2021?

I know the code that keeps subtracting -10 minutes from the current time.

The code will be returned from the infinite loop, and the code will operate until January 1, 2020.

**How can print it out by July 1, 2021 by -10 minutes from the current time?**

### my attempt code

```
import datetime

def before_10minute_time(current_time):
    current_time_minute10 = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10)
    print("Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : " + str(current_time_minute10.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')))

    if_break = current_time_minute10.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    
    if "20210701" in if_break:
        return 0
    
    return current_time_minute10



if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_time = datetime.datetime.today()

    
    
    while True:
        current_time = before_10minute_time(current_time)
```

### output

```
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210813190313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210813185313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210813184313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210813183313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210813182313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210813181313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210813180313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210702014313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210702013313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210702012313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210702011313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210702010313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210702005313



for loop ... output... 

 
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210101004313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210101003313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210101002313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210101001313
Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : 20210101000313
```

---

but error message occured

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'

---

### my goals

How can print it out by July 1, 2021 by -10 minutes from the current time?

Comment: The error is because you are getting `0 - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10)`. You need to break the `while` loop when you hit the `if "20210701" in if_break:` condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As T0ny1234 pointed out in the comment, you are getting this error because you are subtracting a `datetime.timedelta` object to an integer.
Also, you need to `break` the loop when you reach the desired date, returning 0 won't stop the loop.

You can try this:

```
import datetime


def before_10minute_time(current_time):
    current_time_minute10 = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10)
    print("Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : " + current_time_minute10.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
    return current_time_minute10



if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_time = datetime.datetime.today()
    stop_date = datetime.date(year=2021, month=7, day=1)
    
    while True:
        current_time = before_10minute_time(current_time)
        if current_time.date() == stop_date:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
import datetime

def before_10minute_time(current_time):
    current_time_minute10 = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes= 10)
    print("Subtract 10 minutes from the current time : " + str(current_time_minute10.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')))

    if_break = current_time_minute10.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    
    if "20210701" in if_break:
        return 0
    
    return current_time_minute10


if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_time = datetime.datetime.today()
    while True:
        if current_time != 0:
            current_time = before_10minute_time(current_time)
        elif current_time == 0:
            print('20210701')
            break
```

Since you `return 0` at the condition you need to break out of the loop when that condition is met.